# Port a WP7 game to WP8 with Monogame

Tags: xna, monogame, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a full working game for WP7, I want to port it to WP8 with Monogame. I have installed Monogame and I have done all tests to see that it is working inside Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone 8. Now I just don't understand how to rebuild my WP7 version game within a Monogame project to target WP8 devices.

So, if you would have the entire solution of a WP7 game, how would you make it work on WP8 with Monogame?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty broad. You'll need to be more specific about how it's currently not working. What, specifically, is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as I have it, it will probably be easiest for you to create a new Windows Phone 8 MonoGame project from the template and then just copy all the code in. MonoGame uses the exact same namespaces, it just has a lot of behind the scenes changes that make it reference different libraries. Applying these changes whilst also applying all the other changes necessary for WP7 to WP8 project manually will be a complicated and messy task which will probably require hours of troubleshooting to get it working.

Comment: An even easier option would be to just make a copy of his WP7 project and then simply edit the monogame reference.. As far as i know, it should work straight away unless the win8 solution requires some special initialization in program.cs?